# Excel Formula - if function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to conduct a weighted evaluation on different services. The top mark for each offering by this service is 1.00. My likert scale is 1 = very poor, 2 = poor, 3 = average, 4 = good, 5 = very good. I would like to assign a value to each of these ratings (1 = 0.2, 2 = 0.4, 3 = 0.6, 4 = 0.8, 5 = 1) so I can add these up to determine the best service to go with. Not sure how I would write this.

Comment: It will be easier if you show us what you've tried and then we can help. And is your answer not simply to divide by 5 to get your 'conversion'?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you simply need a new column which divides by 5

So in A2, type in

```
= A1 / 5
```

Then type in a number from 1 to 5 into A1 and see the result in A2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you are asking. I think you are saying that you will have text in a cell and that from that text you want it to represent a numerical value. IF that's the case, then this should work:

=IF(A2 = "very poor", "0.2", IF(A2 = "poor", "0.4" , IF(A2="average", "0.6", IF(A2="good", "0.8", IF(A2="very good", "1", "")))))